# How to make a matrix with different list with python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a matrix as:

```
s = [[s11 s12 s13 s14]
     [s21 s22 s23 s24]
     [s31 s32 s33 s34]
     [s41 s42 s43 s44]]
```

where I can obtain each array of the matrix s by:

```
 sii = a(i)  ;  for s11, s22, ... and s44

 sij = b(j)**2 + 10    ;  for s12=s21, s23=s32,s13=s31, ...
```

here, a and b are lists of data:

```
 a = [0.1, 0.25, 0.12, 0.45, 0.98]
 b = [0.1, 0.25, 0.12, 0.45, 0.98, 1]
```

So when I use the following:

```
 import numpy as np


 a = np.array([0.1, 0.25, 0.12, 0.45, 0.98])
 b = np.array([0.1, 0.25, 0.12, 0.45, 0.98, 1])

 i = 4   # matrix order 
 s = np.ones([i,i])

 def matrix(s):

    for i in range(len(a)):
       s[i,i] = a[i]  
    for j in range(len(b)):        
       rc = (j + 1) % (len(b) - 1)
       val = b[i] 
       s[rc+1, rc] = val           
       s[rc, rc + 1] = val        
    return s

 print(matrix(s))
```

It gives me an error. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why `b` have length 10, if you trying to create square matrix?

Comment: Oh. No. That's going to place in the arrays of the matrix except diagonal. For example, s12=s21=0.1, s13=s31=0.25, ...

Comment: Please, see my answer.

Comment: If you see the matrix s, there are s12=s21, s13=s31, s14=s41, s23=s32, s24=s42, and s34=s43 that are filled by list b.

Comment: Could you post your error traceback?

Comment: I updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're better off using library functions.  For the off diagonal element assignment use `triu` and `tril` as below; you can also set the diagonal with `np.diag`

```
import numpy as np

size=5
off_diag=np.array(range(int(size*(size-1)/2)))
diag=np.array(range(size))*10

s=np.diag(diag)
s[np.triu_indices(size, 1)]=off_diag
s[np.tril_indices(size, -1)]=s.T[np.tril_indices(size, -1)]

print(s)



[[ 0  0  1  2  3]
 [ 0 10  4  5  6]
 [ 1  4 20  7  8]
 [ 2  5  7 30  9]
 [ 3  6  8  9 40]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There remain a few problems in the way you've defined your problem, but if you're trying to create the matrix like

```
array([[  1,  12,  13,  14],
       [ 12,   2,  23,  24],
       [ 13,  23,   3,  34],
       [ 14,  24,  34,   4]])
```

from arrays

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34]
```

then you can do this in "pure NumPy" without Python loops:

```
M = np.zeros((4,4))
M[np.triu_indices(4, 1)] = b
M += M.T
np.fill_diagonal(M, a)
```

That is, build the upper diagonal from `b`, make it symmetric by adding the transpose, and then filling the diagonal with the elements of `a`.

Comment: It's getting this error:   >>> M[np.triu_indices(4,-1)] = b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (6,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (13,)

Comment: @ats22 Sorry – wrong offset. It should be `M[np.triu_indices(4, 1)] = b`: I've fixed it in the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Array `a` in your code contains 5 elements, and matrix order `i` set to 4. Matrix `s` will have `shape=(4, 4)` and you trying to address 5-th element.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   s[i,i] = a[i]
```

Try

```
a = np.array([0.1, 0.25, 0.12, 0.45, 0.98]) 
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

i = 5   # matrix order should correspond to a length
s = np.ones([i,i])
```

Comment: @ats22 1. Your `b` list still have more elements, than `a` (I don't know, may be this just typo). 2. Matrix order should be equal to array length (array length in your code 5 for `a` and 6 for `b`) and matrix order = 4.